# Where are inetpub folder and IIS?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis

I have Visual Studio 2010 installed in my machine. But, there is no inetpub folder created. I was not able to find the IIS when I typed out inetmgr in the Run command. Where is the IIS? And why was the inetpub folder not created?

Answer (score 0):

"By default, Visual Studio 2010 SP1 uses the Visual Studio Development Server for Web site projects and Web application projects."

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58wxa9w5(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58wxa9w5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

You would need to install IIS to use the traditional IIS with inetmgr.

Answer (score 0):

As already noted in the other answer, Visual Studio 2010 uses its own Development Server and not the IIS for your web application projects.
You'll need to set up IIS on your system as per instructions detailed [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/03/14/enabling-iis-7-x-on-windows-7-vista-sp1-windows-2008-windows-2008-r2.aspx).
Once that's done, verify the installation by pointing your browser to `http://localhost`